# Is there a way to create a python function that generates a latex document containing the outputs of another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, latex

For example, let's say I create a python function called  `graph(equation)`, which returns a graph of the equation.

How could I create a function, `reportGraph(equation)` that returns a latex file that includes graph(equation)?

For instance, `reportGraph(x**2)` returns a latex file that looks like this:

> This is the result of plotting x**2

> [insert graph here]

In other words, I want to create a latex file that reports the inputs and outputs of a function given a specific template that I design. Any ideas as to how I can do this?

Comment: `sympy` has some sort of `LateX` interface.

Comment: I need to generate a .tex file, like a report. I don't think sympy can do that

Comment: There are quite a few examples of using jinja2 templates to generate latex files on the web.

Comment: `.tex` is only string file so you can use any string functions to generate it - ie. `f-string`, `string formatting` or template engines like `jinja2`

Comment: @furas, that's `tex` as in Latex, not `txt` (plain text).

Comment: you can open `.tex` (latex) in any text editor - so it is only text (plain text) which later can be converted to `.dvi` and `.pdf`. And you can generate `.tex` with any string functions.

Comment: matplotlib has some latex support.